# Running a thread using a variable type of std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I would like to launch a std::function type in a separate thread.
My code currently looks like this :

```
struct bar
{
    std::function<void(int,int)> var;
};

struct foo
{
    bar* b;

    foo()
    {
        std::thread t(b->var); //Error attempt to use a deleted function
    }
};
```

Why am I getting attempt to use a deleted function here ?

Comment: The compiler error tells you which deleted function it is, which will be a big clue. Sadly, you left that part out of the question for some reason.

Comment: Your example is full of errors. But something like this should do the job: `std::thread(&bar::var, b, 12, 12)`

Comment: Are you intentionally not setting `b` to anything?

Comment: no the value of b is set to something i did not mention it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `b->var` is a function that takes two parameters. You need to send these parameters to make it work.

```
struct bar
{
  std::function<void(int,int)> var;
};

struct foo
{
   bar* b;
   foo()
   {
      std::thread t(b->var, 76, 89); // will call b->var(76, 89)
   }
};
```

Comment: Did you try to compile it?